# REST: Tell client to send only csv and text format

Tags: java, rest, web-services

In restfull WS, how to tell client to send only csv and text format file.

In `content-type` header, client set the format in which it is sending request and in `Accept` header, client set the format in which it want to accept response.

But how to tell client to send only `content-type` csv or file ? Is this through some documentation ?

Comment: by "But how to tell client to send only content-type csv or file?" you mean the client should only send csv or file to server?

Comment: Yes...client set content-type...how to tell that they need to set xyz content-type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image you have an endpoint called `/textfiles` - the developer using your API is usually reading your documentation on how to implement this endpoint. Unless you're not doing some auto-discovery magic (which I guess is still not common).

If we take Facebook for example, they just state in their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads/) which files you can send:

> We accept the following files: 3g2, 3gp, 3gpp, [...]

Your question:

> But how to tell client to send only content-type csv or file ?

is also a bit unclear. When the user has sent the request, he already attached the files he thought he could send. So here you would rather send an error with a message, which files are allowed. So are we talking about some "pre"-requests here?

From a backend developers point of view I can just tell you: It's in the documentation. Handle errors properly, document and your implementing developer will not hate you :)

Comment: Thanks. So basically i need to provide documentation for my service which tell the supported format.

Comment: Yes, other people have to work with so they have to know what the have to implement to properly use your API. Just take a look at any provider of APIs, they all have a documentation :)

Comment: @VJS Use a [proper status code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54072692/1426227) instead of relying only on the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @CassioMazzochiMolin . Definitely, I will use status codes. I was confused whether to provide documentation or not...

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin - this should be always done. But I guess a good API consists of a good documentation, suitable HTTP-Codes and meaningful error messages. I was rather looking on it from an initial point of view. And you usually learn which files you can send from the documentation first. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The [`415`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13) status code seems to be suitable for this situation:

> [**6.5.13.  415 Unsupported Media Type**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13)

> The `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code indicates that the
> origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload
> is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated
> `Content-Type` or `Content-Encoding`, or as a result of inspecting the
> data directly.

The response payload could contain a list of the media types supported by the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

if i develop a restful application using spring i would set the produces attribute to return csv or plain text ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) . if the client tries to request a resource other than csv or text it will recieve an error . probably 415